# The rubber band has become loose,is loose

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

If a rubber band loses its elasticity, will it be natural to use "loose" in this context?

> The band has **become loose.**
>
> This band **is now loose**.

Is the use of "loose" in this context natural? Does it mean that the band has "lost its elasticity "?

Or should it be :

> This band has been **stretched** too much.

Answer (score 2):

The two phrases 'the rubber band is loose' and 'the rubber band has lost it's stretch' have similar but slightly different meanings.

'The rubber band is loose' has the meaning that the band is larger than is needed for a specific job, while 'The rubber band has become loose' implies it was not as loose in the past, and thus also implies that it may have lost its elasticity.

If you say 'the rubber band is loose' about a new (still elastic) rubber band, that might mean that is larger than needed for a job you want to use it for.

But if you say 'the rubber band has become loose' that probably means that it was once performing just fine, but has now lost elasticity.

Saying either 'the rubber band has been stretched too much' or 'it has lost its elasticity' both mean the same thing; that the band no longer stretches properly.

Comment: So "the band has become loose" sounds natural, right?

Comment: And you assumed the "towel rubber band" right?

Comment: "The band has become loose." is a valid sentence in English. Not sure how the word 'towel' applies to this question.